# Disable error code arg-type for mypy from mypy.ini or pyproject.toml file

Tags: python, mypy, typechecking

How do I disable error for error code `[arg-type]` in mypy configuration file, either using its `mypy.ini` or `pyproject.toml` configuration file?

I have tried `disable_error_code = [arg-type]`, `disable_error_code = arg-type` and
`disable_error_code = arg_type` in the `mypy.ini` file but none of those solved my issue.

I am trying to ignore incompatible type from the configuration file.

Answer (score 1):

If you really want to globally disable `arg-type` errors across your entire project, you can add `"arg-type"` to `tool.mypy.disable_error_code` in `pyproject.toml`:

```
[tool.mypy]
disable_error_code = ["arg-type"]
```

However, this probably isn't the best idea. Disabling errors for incorrectly typed function arguments cripples a lot of static type checking. More likely, you would only want to disable this lint in a more local scope, and only as needed.

To disable it for just a few modules, you use `tool.mypy.override` tables. For example, to disable it in the module `my_proj.foo` and all modules inside `my_proj.bar`, you can include this configuration in your `pyproject.toml`:

```
[[tool.mypy.overrides]]
module = ["my_proj.foo", "my_proj.bar.*"]
disable_error_code = ["arg-type"]
```

Alternatively, you can add the line

```
# mypy: disable_error_code="arg-type"
```

just to the top of the files you want to disable the error in.

Or for the most limited scope, use a `type: ignore` comment just on the function calls with badly typed arguments:

```
foo("bad")  # type: ignore[arg-type]
```

Comment: Thankyou, this did the trick. But i just realized it might not be the best approach. What i am trying to do is allow type conversion or rather stop mypy from giving me an incompatible type error anytime i do a type conversion in my code.